# Form pop-up message

Tags: javascript, forms, popup

I am using this form processor on my site. Currently when the user hits submit they are brought to a new page to display either the error message or confirmation that the form has been sent. I want the error and confirmation messages to be displayed as a pop-up on the same page as the form itself. Would appreciate any help on this.

```
<?php
/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "mail@mail.com;

/* Check all form inputs using check_input function */

$email    = check_input($_POST['email']);


/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    show_error("E-mail address not valid");
}



/* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
$message = "

Someeone has signed up to your newletter.


E-mail: $email


Regards,

";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

/* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
header('Location: thanks.htm');
exit();

/* Functions we used */
function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
    {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
?>
    <html>
    <body>

    <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
    <?php echo $myError; ?>

    </body>
    </html>
<?php
exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

#### Form Processor

```
/* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
{
    $_SESSION['form_error'] = "E-mail address not valid";
    header('location:' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit;
}
```

#### Form Page

```
if(isset($_SESSION['form_error'])) {
    echo '<script>alert("' . addslashes($_SESSION['form_error']) . '");</script>';
    unset($_SESSION['form_error']);
}
```